# Как сохранять файл каталога в другой каталог на PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста.Как я могу отправить картинку с одного каталога и сохранить её в другом каталоге.
  Пример:

> Есть два каталога Магазин и МагазинМ ,каталог МагазинМ -урезанная версия каталога Магазин.Из МагазинМ отправляется картинка но сохраняется она должна в каталоге Магазин.

А вместо этого происходит обратное.
[image: Примерно вот так]
Вот мой код

```
    // create random image file name
            $string = '0123456789';
            $file = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $_FILES['menu_image']['name']);
            $function = new functions;
            $menu_image = $function->get_random_string($string, 4)."-".date("Y-m-d").".".$extension;

            // upload new image
            $upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['menu_image']['tmp_name'], 'upload/images/'.$menu_image);

            // insert new data to menu table
            $sql_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_menu (Menu_name, Category_ID, Price, Serve_for, Menu_image, Description, Quantity)
                    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            $upload_image = 'upload/images/'.$menu_image;
            $stmt = $connect->stmt_init();
            if($stmt->prepare($sql_query)) {    
                // Bind your variables to replace the ?s
                $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', 
                            $menu_name, 
                            $category_ID, 
                            $price, 
                            $serve_for, 
                            $upload_image,
                            $description,
                            $quantity
                            );
```

> Пробовал вот так:

```
  $upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['menu_image']['tmp_name'], 'Magazine/upload/images/'.$menu_image);
```